# Pointlabels not displaying when data point is at maximum

Tags: jqplot

I have the following graph: http://synicworld.com/media/graph.png

Is there a way to get the pointlabel to show on the bars that have maximum value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pointLabels {
    edgeTolerance: 100
}
```

Looks like it's just edgeTolerance, which I had tried before, but not with a value high enough.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a negative value for edge tolerance?  A high positive value means that the labels are less likely to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

pointLabels {
    edgeTolerance: -20
}

This will allow rendering of point labels even if they're too close to the edge.  The negative value means there might be overlap onto the chart.