# jqplot not display label of value on bar chart

Tags: php, jquery, jqplot

I try to use jqplot to plot a bar graph and I found a problem about first bar in graph, it isn't display point label. How to solve this problem? Thank you for help and suggestion.

Lohkaeo[image]

I'm sorry, I forgot.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        var s1 = [32100,0,0,990000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        var s2 = [36000,0,0,1800,0,4980,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        var s3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        var ticks = ['1 2013','2 2013','3 2013','4 2013','5 2013','6 2013','7 2013','8 2013','9 2013','10 2013','11 2013','12 2013'];
            $('#show-graph').css('height', '699px').jqplot([s1, s2, s3], {
                title:'รายจ่าย',
                seriesDefaults:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barWidth: 20,
                        barMargin: 10
                    },
                    pointLabels: {
                        show: true, 
                        formatString: "%#.2f", 
                        hideZeros: true
                    }
                },
                axes:{
                    xaxis:{
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                        tickOptions: {
                           fontFamily: 'Georgia',
                           fontSize: '10pt',
                           angle: -30,
                           labelPosition: 'middle'
                        },
                        ticks: ticks
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        min: 0
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    location: 'ne',
                    placement: 'insideGrid'
                },
                series:[
                    {label: 'beverage'},
                    {label: 'equipment'},
                    {label: 'another'}
                ]
            });
});
```

Comment: could be a plot configuration issue, where is the code?

Comment: This is because the leftmost bar is too near to the edge so the jqplot will not render that. Try switch to the right a bit.

Comment: thank you sza, how to switch to the right?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I wound up here with the same issue. Found the resolution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607226/pointlabels-not-displaying-when-data-point-is-at-maximum).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the leftmost bar is too near to the edge so the jqPlot will not render that. Try to increase the width.

```
$jqplot('show-graph', [s1, s2, s3], {
    title: 'xxxx',
    width: 1000,
    ....
}
```